# Please explain this C# code snippet

Tags: c#, events, backgroundworker

I see people write code like this

```
_Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
_Worker.DoWork += (sender, e) => e.Result = ((Func<string>)e.Argument)();
```

Why people assign `e.Result` if they don't use it. There is no code below that uses this assignment. 
But! They write below a piece of code where use `RunWorkerCompleted` event. Does `RunWorkerCompleted` event use `e` automatically when rises (precisely this `e` above that I assigned)?

Comment: `e` is sent to the anonymous event.  To understand it a bit better, you need to look at it in reverse. `e`'s values are assigned on the right, but they are defined on the left inside `(sender, e)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. The e.result can be used in the `RunWorkerCompleted` Event. Because DoWork Runs in a own Thread that's the way how you can reuse your results to main thread. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) you can read more about it.
Notice that backgroundworker is a bit oldschool and read about Task Library if you are interested in modern C# Multithreading purposes ( >=.Net 3.5)

Small Example:

```
_Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
_Worker.DoWork += (sender, e) => e.Result = ((Func<string>)e.Argument)();

_Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender,e) => textbox.Text = e.Result.ToString();
```